# Favourite Virtual Desktops Program for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtual-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtual desktop(alt+ctrl+1,2,3,4,…) like linux on windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/65430/virtual-desktopaltctrl1-2-3-4-like-linux-on-windows-7)

Since I recently upgraded to Windows 7, and being slightly irritated with the [Vista & XP Virtual Desktop Manager](http://www.codeplex.com/vdm) (which works even less well on Windows 7), I decided try to try out a new app. I ended up going with [Windows Pager](http://windowspager.sourceforge.net/), which seems to work quite well on Windows 7, though is slightly lacking in features.

What experience have you as Windows 7 (or even XP/Vista) users had with various virtual desktop programs out there? So far I've found nothing that lives up to the VDM of Ubuntu and the lik, yet I'm curious if there are certain ones that anyone would particularly recommend.

Comment: Dupe - http://superuser.com/questions/65430/virtual-desktopaltctrl1-2-3-4-like-linux-on-windows-7/65433#65433

Answer (score 4):

Sysinternals' **[Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx)** enables you to create up to four virtual desktops and to use a tray interface or hotkeys to preview what's on each desktop.

[image]

*Desktops is freeware and portable, no installation required.*

Comment: I don't recommend this one cause it's no aero support :)

Comment: Best choice by far!

Answer (score 3):

Did you say free? Because if you didn't and indeed VDM is giving you problems, you may want to try [Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en).

[image]

I'm however curious as to what type of problems you are experiencing with VDM under Windows 7. I must say I have none. Although, truth be told, I make a very limited use of it.

Comment: Dexpot is free for private use.

Answer (score 0):

As posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/65430/virtual-desktopaltctrl1-2-3-4-like-linux-on-windows-7/65433#65433)

Have a look at [this thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/virtualization/2137-virtual-desktop-7-a.html) in Seven Forums which mentions utlities like

- Deskspace 3D Virtual Desktop -
  [Discussion link](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/3648-3d-virtual-desktop.html) / [download
  link](http://www.otakusoftware.com/deskspace/)
- Virtual Dimensions has support for
  unlimited number of virtual desktops [Download link](http://virt-dimension.sourceforge.net/)
- Crystal Desktop - Allows for grouping
  of windows - [Download link](http://www.cdesktop.brightek-soft.com/)
- VirtuaWin - [Download link](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/)

Deskspace's solution is not free, comes with a 14 day trial.